# How to program the SCPI protocol in Arduino?

Tags: arduino, serial-port, protocols

I want to make an Arduino program that only makes requests for voltage measurement of some sensors through the SCPI protocol connected by RS232. I have found several libraries created by users but they have many unnecessary functions for what I want to do.

Specifically, what is the command to be sent by the RS232 to request the desired sensor voltage?

Thanks.

Comment: Which is the question?

Comment: This is not a coding problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using : Arduino SCPIParser Library by LachlannGunn available on GitHub.

Comment: Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.

Comment: The question doesnt really give any idea about the problem. Maybe if its elaborated I can help.